# Is there a word/term for someone who is interested in many things but is poor/uninformed at most or all of them?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

Years ago I observed a single word/term that used more or less the description above, but I have been unable to locate or remember it since then. I am certain that it was a single word, and thus "jack of all traits and master of none" and other popular phrases don't fit. Any help you can provide would be much appreciated!

Comment: 'Jack of all trades - master of none' is the expression I have heard.

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster says a dilettante is [a person having a superficial interest in an art or a branch of knowledge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilettante). To get the "Jack of all trades" sense you could say "He is a dilettante in several fields."